# Remove specific elements with Streams

Tags: java, string, collections, integer, java-stream

I have these two methods where I want to remove specific elements.

The first one should return the following sequence of numbers: 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 ... The sequence contains no terms divisible by three. The sequence always starts at "4". But in my case it always just prints the paramter from the method.

The second one should delete all spaces from the passed string s1 and outputs the result. (“Hello world, how are you” becomes “Helloworld,howareyou?”). But it in my case it doesn't delete the blanks.

```
static void printFolgenOhne3(int anz) {
        List<Integer> item = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> remove;
        item.add(anz);

        remove = item.stream()
                .filter(i -> anz % 3 == 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        item.removeAll(remove);
        item.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

static void deleteBlanks(String s1) {
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(s1);
        List<String> deleted = elements
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> !x.isBlank())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(deleted);
    }
```

Comment: The second one is not removing the white spaces, it's filtering the ones which are empty. Why don't you do a `String.replace`?

Comment: Your methods don't make sense to me.  In the first one, you are passing a single item, adding it to a list and streaming it.  I suspect you want to pass a `List<Integer>`.  In the second, you can do what  @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo suggested and use a `String.replace.`

Comment: Your `item` collection only has 1 element - `anz`, it's not possible to print other elements, if you don't add them in the first place.

Comment: …and even if there were other elements in `item`, the operation `.filter(i -> anz % 3 == 0)` does not evaluate the item `i` but the invariant condition `anz % 3 == 0`, either removing all elements or keeping all elements. Further, there is no point in collecting all items to remove in a list, just to call `removeAll` on `item`. You can simply do a single `item.removeIf(…);` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the first method,  you can do the following to simplify removal.

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15));
list.removeIf(element -> element % 3 == 0);
System.out.println(list);
```

prints:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your methods should have some input parameters to represent sequences and return appropriate results instead of just printing them.

- Sequence as `List<Integer>`:
  remove divisibles by 3;
  (optionally) ensure that the first number is 4;
  existing sequence not affected, new sequence is created and returned

```java
public static List<Integer> removeDivisiblesBy3(List<Integer> seq) {
    return seq.stream()
        .dropWhile(x -> x != 4)  // optionally ensure to start from 4
        .filter(x -> x % 3 != 0) // keep NOT divisible by 3
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

- Sequence as variable array of `int`s:

```java
public static int[] removeDivisiblesBy3(int ... arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr)
        .dropWhile(x -> x != 4)  // optionally ensure to start from 4
        .filter(x -> x % 3 != 0) // keep NOT divisible by 3
        .toArray();
}
```

- Input sequence as `String`, output result - the string without spaces
  As mentioned in the comments it is enough to use `String::replaceAll` method to remove all unneeded *whitespace* characters from the input string:

```java
public static String deleteBlanks(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // delete all whitespace characters
}
```

---

Tests:

```
System.out.println(removeDivisiblesBy3(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 19, 22)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeDivisiblesBy3(1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 19, 22)));
System.out.println(deleteBlanks("Hello world, how are you?"));
```

Output:

```
[4, 7, 11, 19, 22]
[4, 7, 11, 19, 22]
Helloworld,howareyou?
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can try the below approach using stream:*

**Logic:**

1. I have used `filter` with a condition of element greater than 3 and element should not be divisible by 3.
2. I have used regex for `replaceAll` spaces in the given string.

**Code:**

```
   public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFilteredList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,
                                            7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)));
        System.out.println(deleteBlanks("Hello world, how are you?"));
       }

    private static List<Integer> getFilteredList(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(x -> x > 3 && x % 3 !=0)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static String deleteBlanks(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("\\s","");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16]
Helloworld,howareyou?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the second problem using Stream API:

```
static String deleteBlanks(String s) {
    return s.chars()
            .filter(ch -> ch != ' ')
            .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```